# Converting numpy arrays to an image RGB

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
data = [(22, 21, 2), (217, 210, 166), (250, 240, 230), (276, 270, 260), (232, 234, 249), (274, 282, 270), (258, 266, 264)...]
```

The length is of 256 for an image 16 x 16.

I wanna convert it in the original image, but give me an image of 3*256 like this one:

[image: example]

I´m using this code

`img = Image.fromarray(data.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')`

How can i fix this?

Comment: [Reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This is where `np.reshape` becomes useful.

What you need to do is:

```
Image.fromarray(np.reshape(image_arr, (16,16,3)).astype(np.uint8), 'RGB')
```

This will reshape your array into a 16x16x16 array (rank 3), which is what Image.fromarray expects.

For more information, [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) is the documentation for `np.reshape`

It might also be nice to use the reshape property of NDarrays and do `image_arr.reshape((16,16,3))` instead.

Comment: I apply the code but dont give me the right colors.
These are my first 5 pixels 
data = [(252, 244, 255), (255, 240, 251), (255, 238, 246), (255, 236, 249), (247, 224, 251)...

This is what is giving to me

https://i.imgur.com/Er6ADdV.jpg

Comment: Like zvone commented, a minimal, reproducible example would be nice to debug this issue.